# Preciso de Ajuda com esse Código

Tags: python, if, else

Pessoal eu escrevi o seguinte código simples no meu python:

```
nome = str(input("Qual o seu nome?"))
if nome == 'denise':
  print("Nome bonito")
elif nome == 'maria' or nome == 'pedro' or nome =='joao':
  print("Nome popular no brasil")
else:
  print("Seu nome é bem normal")
```

Se eu escrever Denise  o python imprime a ultima linha "Seu nome é bem normal" e seu eu escrever maria,pedro e etc... mesmo assim o python imprime a ultima linha " Seu nome é bem normal"
Vocês poderima me ajudar e me informar qual o erro desse código?
PS: A versão do meu python é 3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a linguagem Python diferencia letras maiúsculas de letras minúsculas, logo a string `"Denise"` é diferente de `"denise"` e certamente você está escrevendo os outros nomes com letra maiúscula como por exemplo: `"Maria"`, `"Joao"`, `"Pedro"`.

Para corrigir o problema, basta tornar a string retornada do `input()` em minúsculo utilizando o método de string `lower()`, dessa forma:

```
nome = input("Qual o seu nome?").lower() # Transforma em minúsculo

if nome == 'denise':
    print("Nome bonito")

elif nome == 'maria' or nome == 'pedro' or nome == 'joao':
    print("Nome popular no brasil")

else:
    print("Seu nome é bem normal")
```

Um outro detalhe importante a acrescentar, é que o Python não só diferencia letras maiúsculas de minúsculas, mas também ele diferencia letras com acento de letras sem acento.

Sendo assim, a string `"joão"` (com acento no A) é diferente de `"joao"` (sem acento no A).

---

E aqui está uma dica **bônus** para encerrar a resposta:

A função `input()` sempre (a não ser que tenha sobrescrito) retornará uma string mesmo se a entrada do usuário seja numérica. Logo, utilizar o `str()` neste caso é redundante e aumentará o seu código desnecessariamente :)

Comment: Então, eu fiz o que tu falou e mesmo assim não funciona: reduzi o código é escrevi apenas isso. nome= str(input("Digite o seu nome")) if nome =="Denise": print("Nome bonito") e mesmo eu escrevendo apenas isso o python não imprime, apenas pergunta "digite o seu nome" , contudo se eu mudar e colocar o número 1 no lugar de Denise ele imprime. Você sabe me dizer o motivo?

Comment: Não você não fez o que falei na resposta. Agora você verifica se o nome é `"Denise"` (com letra maiúscula), mas se você escrever `"denise"` minúsculo não vai funcionar. Que tal copiar o código da resposta em um arquivo separado, testar o código e estudá-lo para entender onde você está errando ?